# como puedo abrir el Android Studio en la versiones Linux de Debian?

Tags: android, linux

instale el ide de android studio pero cuando lo busco por su icono no lo encuento incluso en la busqueda de aplicaciones no lo veo, en caso de que sea por el terminal, me podria facilitar la instrucion de ante mano por favor y gracias.

Comment: ¿como *instalaste* android-studio?

Comment: Primero que todo, desde donde realizaste la instalación ? desde los repositorios o la instalaste manualmente descargandola desde la página oficial ?.

Comprueba si esta se instalo correctamente con `dpkg -l | grep nombre-del-paquete`, si esta fue instalada, busca en el directorio `/usr/bin` algún nombre que tenga android o studio y mira si ese es el binario, prueba con `ls /usr/bin | grep -i android`.

Answer (score 1):

Esto dependera de la forma como lo instalaste, si descargaste un .deb lo mas comun es que te diga que lo muevas al direcorio /opt/ si ese es el caso debes ir dicho directorio y buscar el binario de android studio e inciarlo con sh, tambien Debian te permite crear un icono de acceso directo pero debes encontrar primero donde isntlaste Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Se abre con el mismo script que se instasla, cuando descargas android studio viene con un script llamado studio.sh la primera vez que se ejecuta instala android studio luego sirve para abrirlo puedes ejecutarlo desde una terminal y se abrira o crear una entrada de escritorio:
Pon en un fichero

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Android Studio
Exec="/ruta/android/studio/studio.sh" %f
Icon=/ruta/android/studio/studio.png
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=android-studio
```

y luego guarda el fichero en /home/tu-usuario/.local/share/applications
despues de esto aparecera en el menu de aplicaciones